# Prove that two angles are equal

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

$M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ in the triangle $\Delta ABC$. $D$ lies on $AC$, and $AD = BD$. $E$ lies on the line $AM$, $DE$ is parallel to $AB$. How can I prove that the angles $D\hat{B}E$ and $A\hat{C}B$ are equal?[image: Figure]

Comment: I found your image unreadable, so I made a new one.  Interesting puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be chosen on the line $AM$ so that $AM = ML$, i.e. $M$ is the midpoint of segment $AL$. Then $ABLC$ is a parallelogram. Thus $AB$ is parallel to $DE$ and $CL$. Let $N$ be the intersection of line $CL$ with line $BD$.

[image]

**Lemma 1.** *Since $AD = BD$, the trapezoid $ABCN$ is isosceles with $AN = BC$ and $\angle \, ANB = \angle \, ACB$*

*Proof:* Indeed, the fact that triangle $ABD$ is isosceles implies that $\angle \, ABD = \angle \, BAD = \alpha$. Furthermore, since $AB$ is parallel to $CN$
$$\angle \, NCD = \angle \, NCA = \angle \, BAC = \angle\, BAD = \alpha$$
and
$$\angle \, CND = \angle \, CNB = \angle \, ABN = \angle\, ABD = \alpha$$ Consequently, triangle $CDN$ is isosceles with $DC = DN$. Therefore triangles $BDC$ and $ADN$ are congruent so $AN = BC$. Hence $\angle \, ANB = \angle \, ACB$.

**Lemma 2.** *The following equalities gold: $$\frac{DF}{NL} = \frac{BF}{BL} = \frac{AD}{AC} = \frac{AQ}{AN} =\frac{QE}{NL}$$ yielding $QE = DF = AB = CL$*.

*Proof:* Look at triangle $BNL$ and the line $DF$ parallel to $NL$. Then
$$\frac{DF}{NL} = \frac{BF}{BL}$$ by the intercept theorem for the pair of lines $BN$ and $BL$ intersected by the two parallel lines $BF$ and $NL$. Alternatively this result follows from the similarity between the triangles $BDF$ and $BNL$. Since quad $ABLC$ is a parallelogram and $DF$ is parallel to both $AB$ and $CL$, the quad $ABFD$ is also a parallelogram so 
$BF = AD$ and $BL = AC$ which implies
$$\frac{BF}{BL} = \frac{AD}{AC}$$ 
Next, look at triangle $ANC$ and the line $QD$ parallel to $NC$. Then
$$\frac{AD}{AC} = \frac{AQ}{AN}$$ by the intercept theorem for the pair of lines $AN$ and $AC$ intersected by the two parallel lines $QD$ and $NC$. Alternatively this result follows from the similarity between the triangles $AQD$ and $ANC$. Finally, look at triangle $ANL$ and the line $QE$ parallel to $NL$. Then
$$\frac{AQ}{AN} = \frac{QE}{NL}$$ by the intercept theorem for the pair of lines $AN$ and $AL$ intersected by the two parallel lines $QE$ and $NL$. Alternatively this result follows from the similarity between the triangles $AQE$ and $ANL$.

*Completing the proof of the main result:* Since $QE = AB$ and $QE$ is parallel to $AB$, the quad $ABEQ$ is a parallelogram, which means that $BE$ is parallel to $AQ$ and therefore $BE$ is parallel to $AN$ too. This means that $\angle \, DBE = \angle \, NBE = \angle \, ANB = \angle \, ACB$.

Comment: How is the point $N$ constructed? You first mention it in the trapezoid ABCN.

Comment: @IanMiller $N$ is the intersection of line $CL$ with line $BD$.

Comment: Ok. I think my confusion is how does $AD=BD$ result in the trapezoid being isosceles?

Comment: @IanMiller Did you figure it out or should I write it in the proof?

Comment: @IanMiller Never mind, I already included it in the proof.

Comment: I was missing the congruence. Much clearer. Thanks.

Comment: How did you get the fractions at the end of your proof? Is there a triangle similarity?

Comment: @idliketodothis The intercept theorem (aka Thales' theorem) or if you prefer, similar triangles... Basically such identities arise when you intersect pairs of lines with parallel lines.

Comment: But DF/NL = CL/QF, no?

Comment: @idliketodothis No. It's the way I have written it.

Comment: I still can't understand how you got those fractions. How can I prove that DF/NL = BF/BL? I noticed that DF\NL = DF/DF + CN and BF/BL = BF/BF+CD, what next?

Comment: @idliketodothis I edited my post. Now you can see the proof of these facts. It's very straightforward.